# Typescript import definition file with a different path than the source

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I get Typescript to point to a JavaScript source file when its path is different from that of the definitions file?

My directory structure looks like this:

```
scripts/
|
+-typings/
| |
| +-lib.d.ts
|
+-program.ts
|
+-program.js
|
+-lib.min.js
```

Program.ts includes this code:

```
import Lib from "./typings/lib";

Lib.SomeFunction(); // etc.
```

But when I try to compile and run it, I get the following javascript error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/scripts/typings/lib.js
```

How can I tell Typescript to look for lib.min.js instead of looking where the definition file is?

Edit: Note that if I move lib.d.ts up into the scripts directory and rename it "lib.min.d.ts" then everything works. But I would much rather have my definitions in a separate folder, and I feel like there has to be some way to specify different paths for the definition and implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the "compilerOptions" property in your tsconfig.json file to include the typings directory.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",  
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./scripts/typings/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's still looking for "/scripts/typings/lib.js" instead of "/scripts/lib.min.js". Do I need to change the import statement somehow?

Comment: You don't have to import definition files to your source code. The Typescript compiler will read the tsconfig.json (if placed in the root directory) and then automatically read / validate the definitions.

Comment: If I don't import the definition file, program.ts won't compile, saying "Cannot find name 'Lib'"

Comment: Are you using the imported "Lib" anywhere inside Program.ts? If no, then remove that line and try again.

Comment: Yes I am. I edited the original question to make that more clear.

Comment: But since lib.d.ts is a type definition file it is not supposed to contain executable functions. *.d.ts files defines what a *.ts file might contain so that Typescript can validate syntax, argument parameter count etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168602/discussion-between-tloflin-and-tejzpr).